# Why is spring boot using threads from different packages to handle requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

So, I just followed this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) to get myself setup with some basic authentication.

In looking at the logs, I had a question about whats going on.  Here is the log snippet:

```
2015-08-24 23:08:22.690  INFO 9732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Aug 24 23:08:22 EDT 2015, principal=user, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 408B23D5ED14118ABBC514260B915F5D}]
2015-08-24 23:08:22.691  INFO 9732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Aug 24 23:08:22 EDT 2015, principal=user, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 408B23D5ED14118ABBC514260B915F5D}]
2015-08-24 23:08:22.693  INFO 9732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Aug 24 23:08:22 EDT 2015, principal=user, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 408B23D5ED14118ABBC514260B915F5D}]
2015-08-24 23:09:50.033  INFO 9732 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Aug 24 23:09:50 EDT 2015, principal=user, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 052AA17446027B428C10624F146B0D84}]
2015-08-24 23:09:50.035  INFO 9732 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Aug 24 23:09:50 EDT 2015, principal=user, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 052AA17446027B428C10624F146B0D84}]
2015-08-24 23:09:50.037  INFO 9732 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Aug 24 23:09:50 EDT 2015, principal=user, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 052AA17446027B428C10624F146B0D84}]
```

To produce these logs all I did was sign in/out twice.  My question is, why is it that the second attempt using a different type of thread?  The first time I logged in it used an `nio` thread, and the second time it used an `io` thread.  Any info as to why this happened or how to configure it would be great.

Comment: It is the same thread. But the name is just capped at a certain length...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring Boot's default log pattern allows 15 characters for a thread's name. When the name is too long, it reduces the name's length by removing characters from the beginning. `nio-8080-exec-10` is 16 characters long so the first character is removed, leaving `io-8080-exec-10`.